# Alternatives to Oracle partitioning

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, partitioning

Are there any good alternatives to Oracle partitioning in free/open source databases?  I'm interested in both partition elimination for queries, and the operational ability to truncate individual partitions without DELETE transactions.

I've seen that PostgreSQL has some support for partitioning with table inheritance, but it seems like a lot of manual effort.

Are there any other options out there?  Is MySQL any better?

Comment: Please take a look at this solution: 'Handmade Partitioning - a working example for Oracle XE/SE' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801407/what-feature-to-use-in-oracle-standard-edition-like-that-of-partitioning-in-orac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle/DB2 have the best support for partitioning into table spaces. I've worked with both solutions, and when you're working with massive amounts of relational data, having the vendor to support you is great.

MySql supports partitioning http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html I've never worked directly with MySql partitioning, but it can be done. There are several partition types, Hash is probably your best option. Keep in mind MySQL cluster is a few versions behind the mainline MySQL release.

Another option, depending your application layer, is to use something like Hibernate shards. Basically, using an algorithm, your application directs the request to the correct database based on definition you provide.

Finally, there is always the NoSQL route if you have the option. Something like MongoDB/Cassandra are built for large datasets, but you lose ACID transactions. VoltDB supports SQL, and I think it supports ACID transactions as well.

Overall, unless you go NoSQL, I would say your options are limited with 'transparent' partitioning like Oracle / DB2.

Comment: VoltDB transactions are "time stamp based" (I just watched a video on it the other day, interesting stuff)..

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I thought I'd mention MySQL's MERGE storage engine for people searching.  You can use it to concat two tables into a single table using a UNION, even across databases.  For applications, it just looks like a normal table.

There are a few limitations:

- Tables must be IDENTICAL
- Only works with MyISAM tables
- If you don't specify INSERT_METHOD, the table will be read-only
- Be careful to have key uniqueness span tables or you will have odd results

More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html