# How can I alter my table to make Oracle merge run faster?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, merge, rdbms

I have a table, DASHBOARD, with a primary key of PERSON_ID.
I want to populate all PERSON_IDs for each column using a MERGE statement that queries another table for counts, ALERT_EVENTS.

I have written MERGE statements for each column, below is one of the queries -

```
MERGE INTO DASHBOARD D
USING
    (SELECT PERSON_ID FROM PERSON) P 
ON (D.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET D.ZONES = (SELECT COUNT(EVENT_ID) FROM ALERT_EVENTS WHERE PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID AND EMAIL_ALERT_TYPE_ID = '40') WHERE D.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (D.PERSON_ID)
    VALUES (P.PERSON_ID);
```

My problem is this query takes too long to run, usually around 50 minutes.

There are 4000 PERSON_IDs in the DASHBOARD table and there are 1.4 million EVENT_IDs in the ALERT_EVENTS table.
The ALERT_EVENTS table is made up of the following columns -

```
"EVENT_ID"            NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"PERSON_ID"           NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"DEVICE_ID"              NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"ALERT_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"EVENT_DATE_TIME" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
"TEXT"            VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
"STATUS"          NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,
"PROC_STATUS_ID"  NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE,
"ALERT_STATUS_ID" NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE

and one UNIQUE index on EVENT_ID.
```

I have tried adding and removing indexes (tried with 1 index and 3 indexes), which doesn't seem to help performance.

Based on my EXPLAIN PLAN (below), I believe I have a table structure problem, as my database always wants to do a FULL TABLE SCAN when executing the MERGE statement.

```
 Operation             Name         Rows    Bytes   Cost (%CPU) Time
 MERGE STATEMENT                4127    314K    21 (5)          00:00:01
 MERGE             DASHBOARD                
 VIEW                   
 HASH JOIN OUTER                4127    120K    21 (5)          00:00:01
 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN  PK_PERSON    4127    16508   4 (0)           00:00:01
 TABLE ACCESS FULL     DASHBOARD    4215    107K    16 (0)          00:00:01
 SORT AGGREGATE                 1   7       
 TABLE ACCESS FULL     ALERT_EVENTS 27  189 5247 (2)    00:01:03
```

I was going to partition the table, but we only have Oracle Standard, and not Enterprise, so it's not an included feature.

How can I speed up this merge statement without using partitions?

I am considering throwing out most of the rows, which would help slightly, but the underlying problem still exists.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Your query has `email_alert_type_id`, but it's not in the definition for `alert_events`. Is that right?

Comment: Please take a look at this solution: 'Handmade Partitioning - a working example for Oracle XE/SE' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801407/what-feature-to-use-in-oracle-standard-edition-like-that-of-partitioning-in-orac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used merge on Oracle, so not 100% sure this will work, but the following should be faster, especially with an index on `alert_events (email_alert_type_id, person_id)` or `alert_events (person_id, email_alert_type_id)`. Ideally you would use the first and see a merge join in the query plan, but I'm not sure if Oracle's query optimizer can do this.

```
merge into 
    dashboard d
using (
    select
        p.person_id,
        count(e.person_id) zones
    from
        person p
            left outer join
        alert_events e
            on p.person_id = e.person_id and 
               e.email_alert_type_id = '40' 
    group by
        p.person_id
    ) x
on
    (d.person_id = x.person_id)
when matched then update
    set d.zones = x.zones
when not matched then insert (person_id, zones)
    values (x.person_id, x.zones);
```

I've also included zones in the insert, it's trivial to remove this to stay in line with the original query.

Comment: I started converting my queries to use this form, and am finding at least 3x improvement in speed, in some cases, as much as 15x.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the numbers of rows being merged was significantly less, only the ones that have values to update, which is awesome. After thinking about it more, I realized we may still have cases where a PERSON has ALERTS on run 1, and the counts are correctly updated in DASHBOARD - but on run 2, after the alerts have been resolved and cleared from the ALERTS table, the count won't be updated to 0 for that PERSON, as there are no records to merge.
Can I update the COUNT to 0 for PERSONS without any matching alerts somehow?

Comment: @Doyle I'd done the count incorrectly, so it wouldn't count 0, I've fixed this now. If you are summarising multiple different things from the alert table, it may be possible to roll all the calculations into a single query.